# Передача объекта в функцию по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
$('.param').append('<div onclick="myFunc('+obj+')"></div>');
```

Получаю SyntaxError: missing ] after element list myFunc([object Object])

Не пойму, где косяк!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for (var val in obj) {
    $('.param').append('<li class="p_' + val + '"><div class="info"></div></li>')
      .find('.p_' + val + ' .info').click((function (aKey) {
        return function () { setInfo(obj[aKey]); }
    })(val));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда объект переводится в строку в выражении

```
'<div onclick="myFunc('+obj+')"></div>'
```

его строковое представление и есть `"[object Object]"`. Таким образом, код который назначается в качестве клик-обработчика

```
myFunc([object Object])
```

что синтаксически ошибочно.

Вам может подойти вот это:

```
'<div onclick="myFunc('+data+')"></div>'
```

а лучше:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
$('<div></div>').appendTo('.param').click(function(){
  myFunc(obj);
});
```

```js
var data = '{"a":543, "c":123}';

function myFunc(item) {
  console.log(item);
}

function testError() {
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  $('.param').append('<div onclick="myFunc('+obj+')">Error</div>');
}

function testNoError() {
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  $('<div>No error</div>').appendTo('.param').click(function(){
    myFunc(obj);
  });
}
```

```css
.param > div
{
  margin:5px;
  border:solid;
  background:green;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="param">
</div>
<button onclick="testError()">Error</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="testNoError()">No Error</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for(var val in obj) {               
    $('.param').append('<li class="p_'+val+'"><div class="info"></div></li>').find('.p_'+val+' .info').click(function(){setInfo(obj[val])});
}
```

Таким образом передается последнее значение объекта, в функцию setInfo().
Осталось догнать, как забиндить цикл...

Comment: будьте осторожны с `find` - если этот код выполнится несколько раз без очищения `.params`, то найденых таким образом элементов будет больше, чем один

Comment: кроме того, `val` по завершении цикла будет названием последнего ключа/свойства объекта, и все клик-обработчики будут передавать в `setInfo` одно и то же